# How to sum the values of a Row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset, like this. and i want to sum the values of each row.

```
ID   F01   F02   F03
1    1     0     0
2    0     1     1
3    1     0     1
```

I need the sum for each row. for example:

```
ID  RowSum
1   1     (1+0+0)
2   2     (0+1+1)
3   2     (1+0+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(F01,0) + ISNULL(F02,0) + IsNULL(F3,0) as RowSum
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.Sheet1$.F01' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.Sheet1$.F02' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.Sheet1$.F03' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.